# Getting the Property Subtype from an FCurve

Tags: python, properties

Is there a way to get a property's [subtype](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/property_subtype_number_items.html#rna-enum-property-subtype-number-items) from an FCurve (e.g. DISTANCE, TEMPERATURE, ANGLE)? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else looking for this answer, it is accessible like this:

```py
def get_subtype(obj,fcurve):
    return obj.bl_rna.properties[fcurve.data_path].subtype
```